# Iterate an array and make queries - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Good evening.
I have this array in MongoDB:
[image]

The array AllegriTeams is the result of a first query on a collection called *coach*. I have to use this array to make a second query on another query called *team*:

```
> db.team.find({_id:AllegriTeams[0].team_id}, {_id:0, official_name:1})
{ "official_name" : "Juventus Football Club S.p.A." }
> db.team.find({_id:AllegriTeams[1].team_id}, {_id:0, official_name:1})
{ "official_name" : "Associazione Calcio Milan S.p.A" }
> db.team.find({_id:AllegriTeams[2].team_id}, {_id:0, official_name:1})
{ "official_name" : "Cagliari Calcio S.p.A" }
```

Is there a way to iterate the array and make the queries on team collection automatically? For example using a for or while cycle?
I tried:

```
while(AllegriTeams.hasNext())
db.team.find({AllegriTeams.next().team_id}, {_id:0, official_name:1})
```

but it does not work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

```
for(var i=0; i < AllegriTeams.length; i++) {
    db.team.find({_id: AllegriTeams[i].team_id}, {_id:0, official_name:1})
}
```

The syntax of your second find is incorrect it should be

```
    while(AllegriTeams.hasNext()) {
        db.team.find({_id: AllegriTeams.next().team_id}, {_id:0, official_name:1})
   }
```

Comment: You are right. While a I was copying I made a mistake. The problem is that I had this error:

TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] has no method 'hasNext'

Comment: The for cycle works but it returns just the last match. What can I do?

Comment: You need to be more clear in your question. Your original problem was that you could not loop through the results and query for specific team info. I have answered that question

Comment: I'll make a new question. Thank you :)